# Why method writeObject in LinkedList is private but never been called?

Tags: java

In class LinkedList, writeObject and readObject are private but never beed called, why and how to call them in Java?

I hava found the answer, Java has reflection to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("xxx"));
oos.writeObject(list);  <-- writeObject will be called here
oos.close();

ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("xxx"));
oos.readObject(list);  <-- readObject will be called here
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean: `ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("xxx"));
list = (LinkedList)ois.readObject();  <-- readObject will be called here`

Comment: Right, my fault, fixed

Comment: I ran your code, it's right. And I set breakpoint in writeObject and readObject of LinkedList, the debug running shows that the two methods are really called. What I wonder is how a private mehtod of a class is called by other class?

Comment: I have found the answer, it's the reflection in Java. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The method is used by java's serialization mechanism. Thus the write method is called by the jvm when you serialize the object. The readMethod is called when you deserialize the object.

See the doc of the [writeMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#861), [readMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html#2971) and of the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Comment: +1 also see the [JavaDocs for Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd yes, thanks Sean Patrick Floyd I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

These methods are used during serialization of the object.

LinkedList implements serializable interface (marker interface) and has provided custom implementation for reading and writing list objects.